# Help with a differential equation using variation of parameters

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

I've been asked to find the general solution of this system:

> $\begin{cases} x_1'= -x_2 + 2 \\ 
>  x_2'= 2x_1 +3x_2 +t\end{cases}$

So, we have been working on this with a friend and were wondering if there's a better method to solve it.

We wanted to used variations of parameters. To start with, we found the eigenvalues:

> $\lambda_1= \frac {3+\sqrt17}{2}$
>
> $\lambda_2=\frac {3-\sqrt17}{2}$

Then, we computed the eigenvectors and found the $X_h$, the homogenous solution. With that, we set out to find $X_p(t$), by solving $Q(t).C'(t)=b(t)$ where $X_p$ stands for a particular solution.

We learned that we need to find $C(t)$ to get $X_p(t)= Q(t).C(t)$ in order to, finally, get the general solution, $X_g$, where $X_g= X_p + X_h$.

In our case, we had:

> $
> e^{\frac{3}{2}t}\left(\begin{matrix}
> 2e^{\frac {\sqrt 17}{2}t} & 2e^{-\frac {\sqrt 17}{2}t} \\
> (3+\sqrt 17) e^{\frac {\sqrt 17}{2} t}&(3-\sqrt 17) e^{-\frac {\sqrt 17}{2}t}\\
> \end{matrix}\right)$. $\left(\begin{matrix} c_1' \\ c_2'\\ \end{matrix}\right) =\left(\begin{matrix} 2 \\ t\\ \end{matrix}\right)$

I prefer to avoid the rest of the computations, I believe they are unnecessarily complicated and you don't need to see them to understand the point.

In short, we found ourselves dealing with a pretty complicated integral to find $C(t)$ and very long computations and started wondering if we were mistaking somewhere or if maybe there's a better method than this one.

Thanks for the help!

(P.S. : How can I write the braces for the system of equations? I tried many times and failed)

**EDIT** Solved the problem with the braces

Comment: This system will probably be a lot easier using undetermined coefficients.  Assume a particular solution of the form $At+B$ where $A$ and $B$ are constant vectors.

Comment: $\begin{cases}
  x+y=1\\
  x-y=2
 \end{cases}$

Comment: @Moo thanks for your answer. I will work this with my friend again. When I asked the question it was late at night, that's why I still don't have news. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a sign error in the matrix you used. You used

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\
 2 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

You should have used

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & -1 \\
 2 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix} \implies \lambda_{1, 2} = 1, 2, v_1 = (-1, 2), v_2 = (2, 3)$$

Please retry your method.

Alternate approaches include Undetermined Coefficients, Laplace Transforms, Matrix Exponential, Fundamental Matrix...

Another approach is to convert the system to a higher order equation by noting from equation $1$:

$$x_2 = 2 - x_1' \implies x_2 ' = - x_1''$$

Substituting those two into equation $2$:

$$x_1'' - 3 x_1' + 2 x_1 = -(t + 6)$$

Hopefully you can take it from here.